# PHP Error in my Server

Tags: java, php, android, server

Hey Guys I have this Java code in ANdroid studio:

```
private void loginUser(){
pd = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if (success) {
                        launchHomeScreen();
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Welcome back " + username,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        loginButton.setBackgroundColor(0x73000000);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    loginButton.setBackgroundColor(0x73000000);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                loginButton.setBackgroundColor(0x73000000);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }){
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
        params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
        return params;
    }

};
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

}

And this at my Server as php code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("x", "x", "x", "x");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colUsername, $colPassword);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    if (password_verify($password, $colPassword)) {
        $response["success"] = true;  
    }
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

And that's the Error I get from my Server:

`[29-Mar-2017 18:24:46 UTC] PHP Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /home/u371648055/public_html/login.php on line 11`

SO I don't understand what's wrong in my Code. I know that the Javacode is correct....so....it's the phpcode..but what?

MY MySQL Database:
[image]

For the problem with the password = 0
Here is that what I send to Server:

```
private void registerUser(){
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            launchHomeScreen();
                            pd.dismiss();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Intent loginActivity = new Intent (RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(loginActivity);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            params.put(KEY_MOBILENUMBER,mobileNumber);
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            return params;
        }

    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

}
ANd that's the register php code:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("x", "x", "x", "x");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$mobilenumber = $_POST["mobilenumber"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

registerUser();

function registerUser() {
    global $connect, $username, $password, $mobilenumber, $email;
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO user (username, password, mobilenumber, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $username, $password, $mobilenumber, $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);  

}
```

How I get the $password:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
   private String password;

  //When clicking the Regsiter-Button:
   pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
   password = pwd.getText().toString().trim();
   registerUser();
}
```

Comment: Most likely your SQL statement is bringing back more than the two columns you're trying to bind to variables. In general using `SELECT *` is not a best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query gets more columns than variables your are passing to the `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` function. Change your select query to get only those columns you need (I'm guessing `username` and `password`):

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT username,password FROM user WHERE username = ?");
```

Comment: Yes, that works..But the JSON sends back success: false...But I send the correct username and password to the server..Look into my QQestion when you need the MySQL DataBase

Comment: Then, post the content of `passwordVerify()`

Comment: How to do? With `$response["success"] =password_verify($password, $colPassword) ;`??

Comment: Try this outside the while loop: `if (password_verify($password, $colPassword)) {
        $response["success"] = true;  
    }`

Answer (score 0):

you need to match the count of `?` placeholders with the count of substitution variables; only then the statement can be prepared for execution:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE ? = ?;
```

Comment: Yes, that works..But the JSON sends back success: false...But I send the correct username and password to the server..Look into my QQestion when you need the MySQL DataBase

Answer (score 0):

Well, most of the answers are correct here and I see your comment.

If you look into the password column, all the rows have the same value 'zero'. Possibly when you debug, you'll find that the password value that you send as post data is inconsistent with the password value for the corresponding row in the database.

Also note that passwords should not be of type int, and that varchar serves better as a password. Try keeping the same password in both your request and the row in the database.
Additionally, post here the value that you are sending from Android, and also that of the password_verify() function if your problem remains.

Comment: I posted the Java code what I sent to my Server and the php code in my server in my Question.

Comment: I saw that you have posted the java code as well as the php code. What I am asking you is to add the value of the password variable that you have passed from android and also the $password value that you seem to catch in the backend service.

Comment: Is that in my Qestion that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, please add it to the question. Preferably, use a debugger...
I'm asking you to tell us the password value that is sent from android and that is received at the server.

Comment: Ok I tested it. The Android send the correct password and the Server receive it correctly.

Comment: your database shows your password should be 0. if it's any other value, then your response will be false.